# ポップアップメニュー内に、画像の表示・非表示切り替えの項目を追加するには

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode6

iPhoneアプリを製作中です。
ポップアップメニュー内に、画像の表示・非表示切り替えの項目を追加するには
どうすればいいのでしょうか？
下記サイトを参考にポップアップメニューを追加したのですが、
http://www.iosjp.com/dev/archives/tag/qbpopupmenu
メニュー内に追加した項目に紐づくメソッドは、引数を使えないようなのです。

```
// ポップアップメニューに項目を追加
QBPopupMenuItem *item = [QBPopupMenuItem itemWithTitle:@"画像消す" target:self action:@selector(GazouKesu)];

// 追加される項目のメソッド
- (IBAction)GazouKesu:(UIButton*)sender {
sender.selected = !sender.selected;

if (sender.selected) {
      self.detailImageView.image = nil;

} else {
    // Update the view.
    [self configureView];
       }
}
```

上記のコードを追加した上で、ポップアップメニュー内の「画像消す」項目を
押したところ、下記エラーメッセージが表示されました。「指定されたメソッドを
探しましたがありませんでした」という意味のようです。

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

試しに、メソッドのsender引数を削除したところ、項目を押しても落ちません
でした（もちろん機能もしませんでしたが・・・）。

どなたか解決策をご教示いただけないでしょうか。
以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

セレクタ（Selector）の記述のしかたから勉強しなおしてください。

```
@selctor(methodName)
```

こう記述すると、セレクタに対応するメソッドは、

```
- (void)mothodName {}
```

こうなります。

```
@selector(methodName:)
```

このように末尾にコロンをつけると、対応するメソッドは、

```
- (void)methodName: (id)sender {}
```

引数がひとつ付く形になります。

```
@selector(methodName:info:)
```

コロンがふたつになると、

```
- (void)mothodName: (id)sender info: (id)info {}
```

引数をふたつ持つメソッドに対応します。

あなたの書いたコード：

```
QBPopupMenuItem *item = [QBPopupMenuItem itemWithTitle:@"画像消す" target:self action:@selector(GazouKesu)];
```

これは、こう訂正するといいでしょう。

```
QBPopupMenuItem *item = [QBPopupMenuItem itemWithTitle:@"画像消す" target:self action:@selector(GazouKesu:)];
```

これで、`QBPopupMenuItem`のインスタンス`item`から、アクションメソッド`- (void)GazouKesu:(id)sender`が呼ばれます。（`(UIButton *)sender`じゃないよ）
本当に呼ばれているかどうかは、

```
- (void)GazouKesu:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"The method 'GazouKesu' was called.");
}
```

で、ログ出力して、確認してください。（修正あり）

**追加の回答：**

コメント欄に「`QBPopupMenu`のバグではないか？」と書きました。そのあと、GitHubから`QBPopupMenu`をダウンロードし、プログラムコードを検証してみたところ、バグというか、実装し忘れの箇所を見つけました。
`QBPopupMenuItemView.m`を開いてください。そして、以下の箇所を修正してください。

```
#pragma mark - Actions

- (void)performAction
{
    if (self.item.target && self.item.action) {
        // [self.item.target performSelector:self.item.action withObject:nil afterDelay:0]; // withObject:をnilからself.itemに変更。
        [self.item.target performSelector:self.item.action withObject: self.item afterDelay:0];
    }

    // Close popup menu
    [self.popupMenu dismissAnimated:YES];
}
```

この修正を施せば、

```
- (void)GazouKesu:(QBPopupMenuItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"The method 'GazouKesu' was called.");
}
```

のメソッドが呼び出せるようになるでしょう。

Comment: すみません、セレクターに「:」を追加し、最後に紹介していただいたメソッドを貼り付けたら「Expecte a type」とエラーが出てしまいました・・・

Comment: エラーメッセージは、もっと長くて、かつ「Expects〜」だと思いますが？引数の型を特定せずにidに修正してみました。これでもエラーになるなら、QBPopupMenuのバグといってもいいんじゃないですか？

Comment: @inu shiba 回答の追加をしました。